# map javascript key with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var cover_or_contain = [
    {1: "cover"},
    {2: "contain"},
    {3: "contain"},
    {4: "contain"}
];
```

`cover_or_contain[1]` this will only return object `{2:"contain"}`, how do I get just "contain"? I can't map `cover_or_contain[var]` with the key.

Comment: If you need to map lots of data using key, I would transform that external array to an object, like @escepta  suggests, and then would operate on that object. Otherwise just use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function or write one if you need older browser support.

Answer (score 2):

Consider change that to this

```
var cover_or_contain = {
    1: "cover",
    2: "contain",
    3: "contain",
    4: "contain"
};
```

then you can access by its key number, like `cover_or_contain[1]`

If you still want to use your notation, you can access it by `cover_or_contain[var-1][var]`

EDIT:
Since the object comes from an external source, you might want to convert it to more convenient format first.

```
function convert(data) {
    var ret = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var k in data[i]) {
            if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
               ret[k] = data[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

cover_or_contain = convert(cover_or_contain);
```

Comment: I can't change the array format, it's an external source

Comment: I added a function to convert it to other format, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for conversion to array; just use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
> Object.values(cover_or_contain[1])[0]
'contain'
```

(`Object.values()` returns an array, hence the trailing `[0]`.)

Comment: @MariaJane I don't understand.

Comment: No need to convert value of the property to an array before getting.

Comment: @TânNguyễn That's why I commented on Borna's answer; it deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

use this **cover_or_contain[1][2]**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cover_or_contain = [
      {1:"cover"},
      {2: "contain"},
      {3: "contain"},
      {4: "contain"}
    ];


    console.log(cover_or_contain[1][2]);
</script>
```

Comment: Even more concise.